# TCP IOCP : Could WSASend post notification to waiting thread after partially sending it's buffer like WSARecv function?

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets, tcp

Instead of sending whole requested buffer, could WSASend/send type of operation return or post notification to waiting thread after partially sending requested buffer when there's too many IO Request to handle? (Similar to how WSARecv/recv function returning/posting notification to the thread after receiving buffer partially if that's what's available in the buffer.)

Comment: `WSASend()` generally does not complete until the entire buffer has been sent, but it doesn't hurt to account for the *possibility* of a partial send by simply calling `WSASend()` again if there is remaining unsent data. A read operation completes as soon as any data is available to return, unless you specify a flag to make it wait until the entire buffer is filled.

Comment: With [RIO](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/10/windows-8-registered-io-networking-extensions.html) you can specify the max number of outstanding requests.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "simply calling WSASend() again if there is remaining unsent data."
Did you mean it literally? Doesn't the program have to check how much data was sent from a previous call and if the buffer was sent partially, it would have to rearrange the arguments of next WSASend() as pointer to the start of its remaining buffer index and its remaining length?

Comment: @JeremyHansen obviously, you have to pass only the unsent bytes, if any, to the next call to `WSASend()`. However you want to do that is up to you, there are several ways to accomplish that.